# Is there anywhere I can download the new USGS Topo TIFS?

Tags: topography

Is there anywhere I can download USGS Topo TIFS?  The new ones?  The USGS site just gives me GeoPDF and their web service restricts the scale you can see them at.
Edit : I am looking for the the new USGS Topo maps (c 2012).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDAL can read the pdf and make it an image format. http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html
GlobalMapper will do the same.

The national map allows you to download the imagery (USTOPO uses NAIP). 
http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/viewer/

Comment: Is the GDAL output PDF georeferenced?

Comment: On the page it states "GDAL supports reading Geospatial PDF documents, by extracting georeferencing information and rasterizing the data." So my assumption is yes.

Answer (score 1):

The [Libre Map Project](http://libremap.org/data/) (through archive.org) has the digital DRGs (tiffs) for all 50 states for free. Only thing is, they are still collared. Go to the Data section for a state and there is a link on the top for the DRGS, here is [Ohio](http://libremap.org/data/state/ohio/drg/) for example.

Comment: Not the same product the OP is asking for. Good source of data though.

Answer (score 0):

ESRI offers the seamless USA Topographic base map, freely through a Map Service named USA_Topo_Maps. As you zoom-in, more detailed maps display. The 7.5 minute quads or 1:24000 scale are the most detailed.